# What is the difference between these dates in Treaty of Versailles?

Tags: world-war-one, date, versailles

There are three dates that are significant when we talk about the end of World War I and the Treaty of Versailles (or at least the ones I have heard of):

- 28 June 1919
- 11 November 1918
- 18 November 1919

What are the difference between them? What happened in each of these dates?

Comment: Doing your homework with the Wikipedia isn't easy enough?

Comment: @TylerDurden Wrong. You're just prejudicing. It isn't even homework.

Comment: This seems to be easily answered by looking up the relevant wikipedia articles on WW1.

Comment: @Semaphore I know what you mean but I still needed help (I do know how to search in Internet and in Wikipedia)

Comment: @PichiWuana It is okay if you need help beyond Wikipedia, but it is expected that you explain what you found and why that didn't answer your question. It seems Wikipedia's articles trivially answers these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The Treaty of Versailles was signed on June 28, 1919.
2. November 11, 1918 was the date the armistice was in force; that day is now known as "Armistice Day" in many countries and "Veterans Day" in the United States.
3. Hindenburg gave his "Stab in the Back" speech on November 18, 1919 which later became part of Hitler's rhetoric.